# Converting Generic Object to a standard salesforce object

Tags: apex, standard-objects

So I have a Generic Object. And i Need that accountRecord to be of Type Account.
Is there a way to directly convert it?

```
public static Account RegisterUser(Object accountRecord){
//LOgic here 
}
```

I tried casting it but it doesnt work. Is there a faster approach than to go a  `Schema.SObjectType AccountConvertType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');`

then manually getting all the fields? im thinking like a direct approach for this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what is populated, you could just serialize then deserialize:

```
public static Account demo(Object data)
{
    return (Account)JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(data), Account.class);
}
```

Comment: +1, though, to be fair, it won't be *faster*, just *less code*. JSON parsing is painfully expensive.

Comment: Thanks so much! This Works! like charm :)